# Eclipse Luna Hangs in Java Debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, freeze

Did some research on this but can't find an answer for my set of circumstances.

**Problem:** I can't start a debug on any Java apps in Eclipse Luna. The progress window tells me that it's "Launching Main" and the progress bar extends to 85% where it hangs. At this point I am given the following beneath the progress bar "Launching: Finding free socket..."

Here's my setup:

- Eclipse Luna (clean install)
- Java is latest (1.7.0_65)
- Windows 7
- pinging both localhost and 127.0.0.1 return good connections
- Debug worked fine with old Juno install
- Project runs fine, behaves properly and returns data, but can't be debugged.
- Not running Avast
- I am running Norton (no previous interference with debug)

Any ideas would be appreciated. I've can't figure out what the heck is wrong with it. I'm sure it's some new variable that Eclipse added that I've never heard of that has to be set, but it sure is frustrating.

Thanks guys.

Comment: If Norton provides a firewall have you told it that Eclipse is allowed to open sockets connections?

Comment: Yes, Norton is aware of the new install of Eclipse.

Comment: Try disabling all software firewalls on the machine and try again.

Comment: Turns out this was a Norton Internet Security 2014 (v21.x) bug of some kind. Even though Eclipse was allowed and port 8700 for the VM should have been open Norton was not honoring the settings. I had to revert (v20.x) to get this opened up. Tried to go back to v21x, but ran into the same problem. Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts related to the network layer typically indicate packet loss.  This can be caused by bad network equipment or a firewall denying access.

When there is no network equipment involved because it is on your local machine, this is typically a problem with a software firewall. This can be verified by temporarily disabling the firewall.