# Eclipse Luna Hanging when Loading Debug Configuration

Tags: java, debugging, freeze, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

Having a problem with Eclipse (Luna) IDE, while running the program I encountered a never ending loop so had to terminate the program. After which every-time I try to re-run the program it just hangs when loading the Debug Configuration.

I am trying to create a Eclipse Plug-in to retrieve a file name and add comments to it. I don't believe there's an error with the program as it was working fine before. I have tested a simple helloWorld program in another workspace to see if there were any problems but that program works fine. From what I have read it could be something to do with the metadata file but I have no idea how to correct it.

**Problem**

When attempting to load the Eclipse Luna box pops up (this is normal) in the bottom right-hand corner of the box, it shows what it is loading. It seems to hang at the point when it is trying to load org.eclipse.web.core.

The program was working fine up before the loop happened and I could run it without any problems.

When Eclipse stops responding it asks "if you wish to close the program" and below that it offers you some problem details which are listed below.

**Problem Details**

Problem signature:

- Problem Event Name:  AppHangB1
- Application Name:    javaw.exe
- Application Version: 8.0.11.12
- Application Timestamp:   539f94f3
- Hang Signature:  8701
- Hang Type:   134217728
- OS Version:  6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
- Locale ID:   2057
- Additional Hang Signature 1: 8701579a6fb10e5d0065e1f36c8dcf91
- Additional Hang Signature 2: 6c5e
- Additional Hang Signature 3: 6c5ef7fd43455b1ace2cb9fa4a881a13
- Additional Hang Signature 4: 8701
- Additional Hang Signature 5: 8701579a6fb10e5d0065e1f36c8dcf91
- Additional Hang Signature 6: 6c5e
- Additional Hang Signature 7: 6c5ef7fd43455b1ace2cb9fa4a881a13

**Have Tried**

Cleaning and rebuilding all projects, disabling firewalls and antiviruses, creating another basic program, reinstalling Eclipse and Java.

Comment: What program are you trying to run?

Comment: Just a simple testing program to retrieve a file name and add comments to it. I don't believe there's an error with the program as it was working fine before also I removed the code that created the never ending loop. I have tested a simple helloWorld program in another workspace to see if there were problems but that program works fine. From what I have read it could be something to do with the metadata file but I have no idea how to correct it

Comment: Why do you mention org.eclipse.web.core? Are you writing Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Have you (really, cleaning and rebuilding all projects) compiled your program? [Are firewalls and antiviruses disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088493/eclipse-luna-hangs-in-java-debug)

Comment: I mentioned it because that's the point where it hangs and yes I am building a Eclipse plug in and again yes I have really cleaned and rebuilt all my projects and cleaned the Java cache, re-installed Java and updated the eclipse plugins to see if that would do anything

Comment: How do you detect the problem point and why don't you post stack trace? (Right click on a hanged thread and use copy stack menu item)

Comment: It doesn't run and that's what ut says on the Eclipse loading screen when I try and run it. Firewall etc all off so can't be them

Comment: Please add exact quote of error message in your question. You last comment make it look like your application won't start, how do you know that org.eclipse.web.core is the culprit?

Comment: @Basieves the problem details in my post are all I get, there is no compile error because the run never completes it just hangs on the loading screen

Comment: Post console output and error log then. Error log is stored in runtime workspace (see launch configuration settings) under .metadata/.log And you have not explained yet why do you blame wst plugin or posted stack trace.

Comment: Put all your comments to question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out, within local Workspace I deleted the .metadata folder and then just re-imported the project this got it working again.

It seems when it got stuck in the loop the **.Lock** file was not closed properly within the .metadata folder and prevented eclipse from starting the Debug Configuration.

These questions also have some answerers that might work as well without having to delete the .metadata folder:

[How do I prevent Eclipse from hanging on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207843/how-do-i-prevent-eclipse-from-hanging-on-startup)

[Eclipse hangs on loading workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972034/eclipse-hangs-on-loading-workbench)

Comment: You only need to delete one file, not whole .metadata folder according to linked answers.

Comment: That was true for them but for my problem I had to delete the whole file to get it to work, as just deleting certain files did not produce any results for me. I added the links for other people who might come across same issue but might only have to delete one of the files to produce results.

Comment: deleting whole .metadata is disasterous never do that! especially when you have a larger projects set!

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue with eclipse Mars running on Linux. I solved it by removing the debug configuration file associated with the project. This file is located in .metadata/.plugins/.org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/$ProjectName.launch